# Write a function using only javascript

Tags: javascript, math, logic

[image: a busy cat](![a busy cat]

I want to solve this using JavaScript but I am having trouble to understand how this works, I know I would need to use a for cycle to calculate it

```
function myFunction(k) {
    var result = 0;
}
```

Comment: What part are you having difficulty with? Knowing what `sigma` does? Creating a loop? Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Basically that, how sigma works

Answer (score 1):

yes you would :) But I don't know if your browser will support such a computation.

```
function myFunction(k) {
  var result = 0;
  for(var k = 1; k <= Math.pow(10,6); k++) {
    result += Math.pow(-1, k+1) / (2*k - 1)
  }

  return 4 * result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You could add the values in a for loop for getting *pi*, [Leibniz formula for π](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80).

```js
function fn() {
    var k,
        v = 0;
    for (k = 1; k < 1e6; k++) {
        v += Math.pow(-1, k + 1) / (2 * k - 1)
    }
    return 4 * v;
}

console.log(fn());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getPi () {
    var result = 0;
    for (var k = 1; k < 10**6; k++) {
        result += ((-1)**(k+1))/(2*k-1);
    }
    return 4 * result;
}
```

This will do.

Comment: You can also use `(2*(k%2)-1)` instead of ridiculous powers of `-1`.